# Parameter returned as a Groovy String instead of the Object

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.0

I have a custom taglib.  I am going to pass the result of the taglib into the g:render taglib.  One of the parameters is an Asset object.  If I call the taglib by itself it works fine.  The parameter is in fact an Asset Object.

Example:

```
templateFinder template="_displayMain" findByFactory="asset" findByObject="${params.asset}"
```

The correctly renders the params.asset as an Asset in the templateFinder taglib.

However once I add it to the g:render taglib it turns into the toString representation of the Asset object.

Example:

```
 render template="${g.templateFinder(template:'_displayMain', findByFactory:'asset', findByObject:"${params.asset}")}" ..../>
```

This results in a Class Cast errorwith class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl' to my Asset class.

I am confused as to why this is rendering as an Object in the first example but a Gstring in the second.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the asset to a string by enclosing it in `"${...}"`.  Try this:

```
<g:render template="${g.templateFinder(template:'_displayMain', 
    findByFactory:'asset', findByObject: params.asset)}" ..../>
```